# javascript code to add 2 digit decimal numbers are rounding off to whole integers

Tags: javascript

Forgive my javascript ignorance - I'm strictly a php developer

```js
function checkTotal() {
  document.listForm.total.value = '';
  var sum = 0;
  var o = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.listForm.choice.length; i++) {
    if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
      sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
      o++;
    }
  }
  if (o > 1) {
    sum = sum - 0;
  }
  document.listForm.total.value = sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10.25" onChange="checkTotal()" />Pizza<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="9.75" onChange="checkTotal()" />Salad<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="12.50" onChange="checkTotal()" />Wings<br/> Total:
  <input type="number" size="5" name="total" value="0" />
</form>
```

The results were `10.00`,  `9.00`  & `12.00`   (this does add correctly to 31.00)

should be:  `10.25 + 9.75 + 12.50 = 32.50`

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` will parse your string without recognizing a decimal point: by parsing each of your values via `parseInt`, you're going to wind up dropping the decimal from each one. `parseFloat` will parse your string into a floating point number, keeping those decimal values around.

```
 function checkTotal() {
    document.listForm.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;        var o = 0;
    for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
      if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
        sum = sum + parseFloat(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
          o++;
      }
    }
    if (o>1) {sum=sum-0;}
    document.listForm.total.value = sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkTotal() {
  document.listForm.total.value = '';
  var sum = 0;
  var count = 0;
  // for-of iteration is easier if you don't need index. BTW you forgot "var" in for-i
  for (var ch of document.listForm.choice) {
    if (ch.checked) {
      // as ch.value is properly formatted number, you can use unary "+"
      // (or actually any math operator except "a+b" cuz it adds strings)
      // (+n), Number(n) and parseFloat(n) are generally equivalent
      sum += (+ch.value);
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count > 1) {
    sum = sum - 0; // why is this, didn't get it
  }
  document.listForm.total.value = sum//.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10.25" onChange="checkTotal()" />Pizza<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="9.75" onChange="checkTotal()" />Salad<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="12.50" onChange="checkTotal()" />Wings<br/> Total:
  <!-- + readonly --!>
  <input type="number" size="5" name="total" value="0" readonly />
</form>
```